# Is it possible to redirect to another URL if today's date is greater than perticular date with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 directory like **"comingsoon"**(Files for coming soon page) and **"default"** *(my website)*.
I want to load "default" directory if today's date is greater than perticular date else it must load "comingsoon" directory.

**Example:**
If given date 29/02/2014 and today's date 27/02/2014, then as per rule "comingsoon" must be redirected and when date will become greater than 29/02/2014 then "default" directory must be load

I can do it with php code but i want to do it with .htaccess to avoid slow loading and code checking from index file..
I have gone through some "expiry date" concept from .htaccess..
I have generate .htaccess file too from http://www.htaccessredirect.net/

But nothing look so easy for compare..

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your .htaccess file with CRON.

This is a good introduction : https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab

You'll need two files : htaccess_comingsoon and htaccess_default

And two rules :

```
cp -f /your/directory/comingsoon .htaccess
```

and

```
cp -f /your/directory/default .htaccess
```

In the rule, you can define at which moment these will get executed.

Comment: can u please explain how to do it? or any reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rewrite condition for your rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{TIME} >2014022900000
RewriteRule ^comingsoon/(.*)$ /default/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```